# Hide element if click outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to close the search bar if I click anywhere but the search bar elements (input and submit button). What I made so far is use toggle to open and close it and this is working. But I couldn't find a way so far to close it if I click anywhere outside the div.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/hateusall/pen/abdedJE

HTML:

```
<header>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            
              <div class="navbarCustom pleft pright ">
               <div class="navbar-brand">
                  <img src="./images/x.png" alt="x" class="header-logo">
               </div>
               <ul class="list-unstyled d-xl-flex align-items-center navbar-custom">
                  <li class="dropdown " >Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Lorem Ipsum </li>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </div>
                  <li> Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li> <button class="btn-wpp"> Whatsapp </button></li>
                  <li class="position-relative wrapper-bar">
                    <div class="search-icon search-toggler">
                    <i class="fas fa-search search"></i></div>
                 <div class="search-wrapper" >
                     <form action="#" class="">
                         <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-input" id="info">
                          <button class="border-0 bg-dark text-white p-2 btn-search"><i class="fas fa-search" id="info2"></i></button>
                     </form>
                 </div>
                 
                </li>
             
               </ul>
               <div class="navbar-toggler text-white d-xl-none">
                  <span class="line line1"></span>
                  <span class="line line2"></span>
                  <span class="line line3"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>

    const searchToggler = document.querySelector(".search-toggler");
       const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-wrapper");
  
       searchToggler.addEventListener("click", function(e){
          
 
       if ( !$(event.target).hasClass('search-toggler')) {
         $(searchWrapper).toggleClass("search-wrapper-active");
          close();
    } 

});
    function close() {
      if (!$(event.target).hasClass('search-wrapper-active')) {
         $(document).click(function(e){
            /* here i would remove active classes */
           console.log("test")
         })
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats your expected output ? YOur questions is not clear sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry. What I made is show a div on click and when I click it, it hides. I used toggle to make this. but what I want is if I click anywhere outside the div it closes

Comment: can you add the html code as well pls, and also all your relevant js codes. the code provided seems in complete and wont even run

Comment: Just added more info. Sorry about the incomplete post.

Comment: Also add CSS, make [mre] in order to help us help you. Make a snippet by pressing  `<>` button in editor.

Comment: Just added a codepen with all the infos

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    [...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
//get all elements in body
      el.addEventListener('click', event => {
//add addEventListener
        if (event.target.className.includes("search") === false) {
//if clicked element does not have class search
          searchWrapper.classList.remove("search-wrapper-active");
//remove search-wrapper-active class to close it
        }
  })
})
```

And that way you don't need anything else, just combine it together to close it and open (also benefit, using only JS):

```
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-wrapper");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.className.includes("search") === false) {
      searchWrapper.classList.remove("search-wrapper-active");
    } else {
      searchWrapper.classList.toggle("search-wrapper-active");
    }
  })
})
```

**Keep in mind now**:

now you have event listener on all elements on page, if you need it for something else, just expand this to suit your needs, no need to add  event listener click again anywhere.

```js
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-wrapper");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.className.includes("search") === false) {
      searchWrapper.classList.remove("search-wrapper-active");
    } else {
      searchWrapper.classList.toggle("search-wrapper-active");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.search {
  cursor: pointer !important;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: relative;
}

.search-active {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: .4s all ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: all !Important;
}

.search-input {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.search-image {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.search-submit {
  z-index: 99999999999999999999;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: all !Important;
}

.toggler-image {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
}

.search-input {
  border-radius: .2rem;
  padding-left: 16px;
  z-index: 9;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.search-toggler {
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.search-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
  position: absolute;
}

.search-wrapper-active {
  transform: translateY(35px);
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out all;
}

.btn-search {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px;
}

header {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 32px 0px;
}

.pleft {
  padding-left: 380px;
}

.custom-cont {
  padding-left: 380px;
  padding-right: 280px;
}

.pright {
  padding-right: 280px;
}

.navbarCustom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header li {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 49px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: var(--mbold);
  cursor: pointer;
}

header li:hover {
  color: #4aba58;
  transition: .3s;
}

header ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.btn-wpp {
  background-color: #4aba58;
  border: none;
  padding: 17px 21px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  transition: .4s;
}

.btn-wpp:hover {
  filter: brightness(120%);
  transition: .4s;
}

.cart-value {
  background-color: var(--verdeClaro);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 13px;
  transform: translate(80%, -80%);
}

.cart-value:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbarCustom pleft pright ">
          <div class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="./images/x" alt="x" class="header-logo">
          </div>
          <ul class="list-unstyled d-xl-flex align-items-center navbar-custom">
            <li class="dropdown ">Lorem </li>
            <li class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Lorem Ipsum </li>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
            </div>
            <li> Lorem </li>
            <li> <button class="btn-wpp"> Whatsapp </button></li>
            <li class="position-relative wrapper-bar">
              <div class="search-icon search-toggler">
                <i class="fas fa-search search">toggler</i> </div>
              <div class="search-wrapper">
                <form action="#" class="">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" class="search-input" id="info">
                  <button class="border-0 bg-dark text-white p-2 btn-search"><i class="fas fa-search" id="info2"></i></button>
                </form>
              </div>

            </li>
            <li class="cart position-relative">
              <div class="cart-value">1</div>
              <img src=".//images/carrinho.png" alt="">
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="navbar-toggler text-white d-xl-none">
            <span class="line line1"></span>
            <span class="line line2"></span>
            <span class="line line3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <h1>TEST
      <h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/hekepesusu/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
const $toggler = $(".search-toggler");
const $wrapper = $(".search-wrapper");

$toggler.on("click", function() {
  $wrapper.toggleClass("search-wrapper-active");
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if ($(".search-toggler, .search-wrapper").has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $wrapper.removeClass("search-wrapper-active");
  }
});
```